# Close connection when using a Transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, transactions

I have the following method which uses a transaction.

```
private string getDocumentDetailsByNumber(string DocNumber)
    {
       SqlTransaction transaction = DALDBConnection.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                DataSet DocNum = new DataSet();

                string sDocNumber = "";
                string[] taleNamesDoc = new string[1];
                taleNamesDoc[0] = "docnumber";
                SqlParameter[] paramDoc = new SqlParameter[1];
                paramDoc[0] = new SqlParameter("@DocumentNumber", DocNumber.ToString().Trim());

                SqlHelper.FillDataset(transaction, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spGetDocumentDetailsByNumber", DocNum, taleNamesDoc, paramDoc);
                string docTitle = DocNum.Tables["docnumber"].Rows[0][0].ToString();


                transaction.Commit();

                return docTitle;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                transaction.Rollback();
                throw ex;
            }

    }
```

after running the method several times, user ended up getting the error message below.

> the timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the
>   pool

Error occurred because I haven't closed the connection and the connection pool has over flown.

I tried to close the connection before committing the transaction.

```
transaction.Connection.Close();  
transaction.Commit();
```

Then got the following error.

> This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable

How can I close the connection to avoid the error?

Comment: you can use using (SqlTransaction tran = new SqlTransaction())
            {
//You code
            }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, you should dispose of the connection properly. I've modified your code to demonstrate. Please note you will need to substitute the connection string with yours.

```
private string getDocumentDetailsByNumber(string DocNumber)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("My Connection String"))
    {
        SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

        DataSet DocNum = new DataSet();

        string sDocNumber = "";
        string[] taleNamesDoc = new string[1];
        taleNamesDoc[0] = "docnumber";
        SqlParameter[] paramDoc = new SqlParameter[1];
        paramDoc[0] = new SqlParameter("@DocumentNumber", DocNumber.ToString().Trim());

        SqlHelper.FillDataset(transaction, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spGetDocumentDetailsByNumber", DocNum, taleNamesDoc, paramDoc);
        string docTitle = DocNum.Tables["docnumber"].Rows[0][0].ToString();

        transaction.Commit();

        return docTitle;
    }  // Connection is disposed and cleaned up. 
}
```

Opening new connections are cheap and should not be frowned upon. Each one you call the database you should open a new one like this. By maintaining a connection and not disposing of it, you are taking resources away from the database as well. It does not have an infinite amount of connections in its pool that can be used at once.

**edit**

Removed try/catch as mentioned in comments. If an exception is thrown while in the using block, a rollback will occur and the exception passed up the stack.

Comment: Putting the Transaction in a using block, too, would get rid of the whole exception handling.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I've never encountered an exception in a using block. Is an exception swallowed when thrown in a block?

Comment: No, the transaction is disposed by the using block, resulting in a rollback. The exception is passed on normally and can be caught at a higher level. That's the point of using blocks: they *will* dispose the object, no matter how they are left.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I didn't realize it would automatically handle a rollback upon an exception being thrown. That's a nice piece of info to know.

Comment: SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(); throws Invalid operation. The connection is closed.

Comment: I have code very similar to this. However, when I query the database, I find that - even though I committed the transaction in code - the transaction on the database is still open, locking tables. The session is sleeping, but the transaction is open, and I can't figure out how to close the damn thing.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot exhaust your pool by using a single connection. You need to close all connections you are using. Preferably *after* the transaction has ended one way or another. `using` blocks are your friend for almost all database related objects.

By the way:

```
throw ex;
```

This damages your exception by replacing the original stacktrace. Use:

```
throw;
```

to rethrow the exception you caught unchanged.

Comment: So if I use using (SqlTransaction transaction = DALDBConnection.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction())
        { // my code } does it close the connection? and does it still close the connection after the return statement?

Comment: No, it does not. The connection itself should be in a using block.

Answer (score -3):

Have you considered CALLNIG CLOSE ON IT? Would be obvious to close a connection or?

Anything that implements IDIsposable should be disposed, btw., not just closed. And SqlConnection implements IDisposable. THis has nothing to do with SqlTransaction - you violae a fundamental rule of the .NET world by not disposing a disposable routine.